# Visualization using pcolormesh in python

Tags: python, visualization

in my script I use plt.pcolormesh to visualize my data.
The following code is a simplification, but should help me to explain my problem.
In the example I created two vectors X and Y, both containing values from 0 to 9.
X and Y represent coordinates.
Z is defined to have the value 2, only the points between the X/Y-coordinates 3 and (including) 6 get the value 4.
Hence, Z can be seen as value for each coordinate.

My aim is to use plt.pcolormesh to color the area between these coordinates in a different color than the surrounding area.
But if I use plt.pcolormesh, also the quadrant above and to the right of the X/Y-coordinate is colored.

I know that I simply could change the definition of my X/Y-variables, but this isn't possible in my original code.
Thus, I want you to ask if there is a function in python which works similar to plt.pcolormesh, but only colors the area between my defined coordinates?

I hope, someone can help me ;)

```
X, Y = np.mgrid[slice(0,10,1), slice(0,10,1)]
Z = 2 * np.ones((10,10))
Z[3:7,3:7] = 4    

plt.figure()       
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.rainbow)  
plt.title('Test Meshgrid')
plt.colorbar()
```

Best regards,

Kai

Comment: May be you need to interpolate Z.

Comment: In the original code I use a 16x16 grid in the x-y-plane. This results in a calculation time of say 1 minute. If I increase the resolution due to your suggested interpolation I fear a significantly higher computational effort...